# Javascript, case insensitive, rock, paper, scissors

Tags: javascript

I have made a rock, paper, scissors game using javascript and have completed the basic function: rock beats scissors etc. but now I am trying to make it case insensitive with the answers please help and thanks.

this is my code if it helps

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?Type your answer.     Refresh page to start again!");//Initial dialogue
var computerChoice = Math.random();//computer chooses a random number
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
//Above: if computer chooses a number it is equal to rock, paper or scissors
var compare = function(choice1, choice2)  //variable of computer and user choice
{
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
    return console.log("The result is a tie!)";//If the user and computer chooses the same then text
}
if(choice1 === "rock" ) {
    if(choice2 === "scissors") {
        return console.log("rock wins");
    } else {
        return console.log("paper wins");
    }
}
if(choice1 === "paper") {
    if(choice2 === "rock") {
        return console.log("paper wins");
    } else {
        if(choice2 === "scissors") {
            return console.log("scissors wins");
    }
}
if(choice1 === "scissors") {
    if(choice2 === "rock") {
        return console.log("rock wins");
    } else {
        if(choice2 === "paper") {
            return console.log("scissors wins");
        }
    }
}
}  //Abover: Rock beats scissors, paper beats rock, scissors beats paper and dialogue

console.log("User Choice: " + userChoice);
console.log("Computer Choice: " + computerChoice);
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Comment: You should also test that the user actually entered one of "rock", "paper" or "scissors" (and not some other value).

Comment: That was my next step after this, to display a message if they don't enter the correct response. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

To make JS case insensitive, transform the text to lowercase :

`var text = 'InPuT';`

`text = text.toLowerCase();`

So `InPuT` becomes `input` and then you can test it like :

`if(text=='input'){ //... }`

Hope it helped you ;)

Comment: Or you can do the opposite :
`text.toUpperCase()`

Comment: I've just seen that @GerardoFurtado said it too. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot the response came quicker than I was expected :) got it now